# Semijoin expression must be a part of logical AND

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table (we can call it "A") with some fields (model:string, age:integer, code1:integer, code2:integer, code3:integer) and another table (it can be "codes") with classified codes (code:integer,codetype:string,description:string).

That field codetype is there in order to group codes. For example, codes between 200 and 300 are brown. And every item can have up to 3 codes.

Now, I just want to get that simple, simple query:

```
SELECT model,age FROM dataset.A
WHERE code1 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown')
```

and it works, except the fact, there are two other ones. So, if I do in this way:

```
SELECT model,age FROM dataset.A
WHERE code1 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown')
OR code2 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown')
OR code3 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown')
```

it doesn't work and I get this error message:

```
Error: (xx:yy): Semijoin expression (i.e. "x IN (SELECT ...)") must be a part of logical AND.
```

I am sure Google should have a way to do this.

By the way, the project I am developing is not with "A" and "codes". I really need a solution for this. Thanks any help.

Answer (score 7):

BigQuery indeed currently has limitation that IN subqueries must be connected with ANDs. As a workaround, you may execute each SELECT separately, and then UNION the results, i.e.

```
SELECT model, age FROM
(SELECT model,age FROM dataset.A
WHERE code1 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown')),
(SELECT model,age FROM dataset.A
WHERE code2 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown')),
(SELECT model,age FROM dataset.A
WHERE code3 IN (SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown'))
```

This may result in duplicates of (model, age) pairs, so if this is not desired, you can remove duplicates using `GROUP BY model, age`

Comment: I really appreciate your answers. The situation is, that is a query generator for dummy users. That change means a big one. Do you you have idea if there is a solution on the way for that limitation?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of elements you're selecting in the semijoin is small, you cold break it into two queries: the first would get the values you're looking for, the second would compute the semijoin (the restriction on semijoins is only when the IN clause is a subselect, not when it is a concrete list). That is, first do

```
SELECT code FROM dataset.codes WHERE codetype='brown'
```

and let's say the results are `'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`

Then you could do:

```
SELECT model,age FROM dataset.A
WHERE code1 IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
  OR code2 IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
  OR code3 IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

This isn't a pretty solution, but it might be a reasonable workaround.