# Combination of AND and OR conjunctions with nested SELECT clauses in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have a dynamic UI query builder which builds BigQuery constructs based on the actions done by the users. The queries are like(in words) :

- Users who viewed products
- Users who viewed products AND added them to cart
- Users who viewed products OR added them to cart AND placed an order

To support such kind of queries we initially used nested SELECT clauses. For example, the second query above will look similar to this in SQL :

```
SELECT email FROM users JOIN actions ON users.email = actions.user_id
WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM users JOIN actions
                ON users.email = actions.user_id
                WHERE action = 'view_product')
AND action = 'add_product_to_cart'
```

This works fine so far. Now, the query "users who viewed products OR added to cart" will not work because of this error- [Semijoin expression must be a part of logical AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526966/semijoin-expression-must-be-a-part-of-logical-and). To make OR conditions work, we are willing to take the path of UNIONs.The query will then look thus :

```
SELECT email FROM
    (SELECT email FROM users JOIN actions
     ON users.email = actions.user_id
     WHERE action = 'view_product'),
    (SELECT email FROM users JOIN actions
     ON users.email = actions.user_id
     WHERE action = 'add_product_to_cart')
```

The question is, how to support a combination of both AND and OR conjunctions? Since UNIONs in BigQuery apparently don't work in WHERE clauses, how do I combine the nested subqueries?
Specifically, how do I write a query for the third bullet point above?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to [use standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). Then you can do:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email FROM users
WHERE (
  SELECT
    (COUNTIF(action = 'view_product') > 0 OR
     COUNTIF(action = 'add_product_to_cart') > 0) AND
    COUNTIF(action = 'placed_order') > 0
  FROM actions
  WHERE email = user_id
);
```

BigQuery's standard SQL dialect has fewer limitations than legacy SQL does, which are detailed in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: This is already possible in the legacy SQL. Query #2 is essentially the same thing, I guess. UNION inherently means OR. However, the problem is combining AND and OR for nested subqueries, e.g., query for thi statement - _users who viewed products OR added them to cart AND placed an order_.

Comment: See if this edit helps. I thought the issue was just the legacy SQL limitation at first.